# 'ListWrapper' object has no attribute 'get_config' error when saving nested model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

On Tensorflow 2.3.0, I am using [Tensorflow Keras WideDeep model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/experimental/WideDeepModel) and am having an issue when calling `model.save(path)`.

The error I am receiving is
`AttributeError: 'ListWrapper' object has no attribute 'get_config'`

I have tested my code with other models and the save function works properly.

I also noticed that `tensorflow.keras.utils.plot_model(model, path+f'{modelName}.png', show_shapes=True, rankdir='TB', expand_nested=True)` does not render a graph.

The original model used tensorflow.keras LinearModel for the wide and a DNN for the deep. [After reading this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59443567/listwrapper-object-has-no-attribute-name-when-plotting-keras-custom-model), I have tried taking out the WideDeep and Linear Keras models and rebuilding as functional nested models. My new setup has a similar error `AttributeError: 'ListWrapper' object has no attribute '_HAS_AGGREGATE_GRAD'`

I think my error has something to do with using multiple inputs passed in as a list to a nested model. Has anyone had similar experiences saving Tensorflow Keras WideDeep or functional nested models?

[A link to a copy of my code. The error message is presented in "Evaluate Network:Test Model"](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1iZMD2tilJHrjQjnWmWPLa1MtvXZN3zzB?usp=sharing)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, sorry for my non-professional answer.

I had that problem, too.

If your train feature 1 is `train_feature_1`, then

Instead of `model.fit( [train_feature_1, train_feature_2], [train_label_1, train_label_2], epochs = 2 )`

Put `[np.array(train_feature_1), np.array(train_feature_2)]` in `model.fit(~~~)`