# 'ListWrapper' object has no attribute 'minimize'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I am coding a GAN with a multi-output discriminator. Trying to train the discriminator in batches but getting the error - AttributeError: 'ListWrapper' object has no attribute 'minimize'.
Following is the discriminator code, here c_model is the discriminator with multiple output-

```
# custom activation function
def custom_activation(output):
    logexpsum = backend.sum(backend.exp(output), axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    result = logexpsum / (logexpsum + 1.0)
    return result

# define the standalone supervised and unsupervised discriminator models
def define_discriminator(in_shape=input, n_classes=n_class):
    # image input
    in_image = Input(shape=in_shape)
    # downsample
    fe = Conv2D(128, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(in_image)
    fe = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(fe)
    # downsample
    fe = Conv2D(128, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(fe)
    fe = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(fe)
    # downsample
    fe = Conv2D(128, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(fe)
    fe = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(fe)
    # flatten feature maps
    fe = Flatten()(fe)
    # dropout
    fe = Dropout(0.4)(fe)
    # output layer nodes
    fe = Dense(n_classes)(fe)
    # supervised output
    c_out_layer = Activation('softmax')(fe)
    # unsupervised output
    d_out_layer = Lambda(custom_activation)(fe)


    # The part of discriminator that is giving the error
    # define and compile supervised discriminator model
    c_model = Model(inputs = in_image, outputs = [c_out_layer, d_out_layer])
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.0002)
    c_model.compile(loss=['sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 'binary_crossentropy'], optimizer=[opt, opt], metrics=['accuracy', 'accuracy'])


    # define and compile unsupervised discriminator model
    d_model = Model(in_image, d_out_layer)
    d_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer = opt)
    return d_model, c_model
```

Following is the code snippet for training the model -

```
c_loss, c_acc = c_model.train_on_batch(Xsup_real, [ysup_real, label_real])
```

The input shape for the 3 inputs are -

```
Xsup_real = (60, 64, 64, 1)
ysup_real = (60, 1)
label_real = (60, 1)
```

The tensorflow version is 2.6.0 and keras version is 2.6.0
Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Could you attach the error stack trace too? Attaching similar issue for reference . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59443567/listwrapper-object-has-no-attribute-name-when-plotting-keras-custom-model

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the following call

```
c_model.compile(
    loss=['sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 'binary_crossentropy'],
    optimizer=[opt, opt],
    metrics=['accuracy', 'accuracy']
)
```

You cannot pass multiple optimizers into the `compile` function as a list. If really necessary, use [tfa.optimizers.MultiOptimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/optimizers/MultiOptimizer) from `tensorflow-addons` instead.

```
multiOpt = tfa.optimizers.MultiOptimizer(
    [(opt, c_out_layer), (opt, d_out_layer)]
)
c_model.compile(
    loss=['sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 'binary_crossentropy'],
    optimizer=multiOpt,
    metrics=['accuracy', 'accuracy']
)
```

But, looking at your code more closely, you probably don't even need to have multiple optimizers. Just do

```
c_model.compile(
   loss=['sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 'binary_crossentropy'],
   optimizer=opt,
   metrics=['accuracy', 'accuracy']
)
```